# Using the Right Translation file in Symfony Manually

Tags: php, symfony, translation

I do not have access do composer or any command line tool on the environment, so I'm doing it manually.

Problem is: I didn't find any route to the translation file I want do use (mynewBundle/resources/translation/messages.pt.xlf) and it's using the translation file of the original bundle I used as reference (oldBundle/resources/translation/messages.pt.xlf).

Where can I change this setting?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Symfony will collect translations from various sources by default:

- `app/Resources/translations/`
- `app/Resources/<BundleName>/translations`
- inside the bundle: `Resources/translations`

Symfony will load translations in priority from these folders, so you can overwrite the translations inside a bundle by putting the new ones into `app/Resources/<BundleName>/translations`. If you have both, the old and new bundle, still inside your project than it could very well be that the old translations have a higher priority by means how the bundles are loaded.

If you can't remove the old bundle then you best chance is, to place the new translations into `app/Resources/MyNewBundle/translations/messages.pt.xlf`, instead of leaving them inside the bundle.

Comment: Hum, Didn't work.
My app/Resources/ has no translations at all... 
All my translations files are in:

src/Ahms/MyBundle/Resources/translations

.
Each bundle inside Ahms has it own translations folder. 
Is there any place I can view/edit the priority of these translations?

Well, the project itself uses Symfony AND Mediboard. Maybe that's why it's that mess...

Thanks anyway!

Comment: I think inside the bundles it will be sorted either by name or in the order the bundles are registered in the Kernel. You might also be able to gather more info from the debug toolbar in the translation panel